# Remember to start app with elevated privileges

Tags: c#, uac

I have an application that needs to get the harddisk serial number to check against a license. Currently I'm doing this using WMI but this is always causing troubles.

My idea now was to use a combination of CreateFile and DeviceIoControl, but these ones require elevated privileges to run properly.

Since I need to check the license on each application startup this would mean that I have to ask the user that the application starts in admin mode, which is pretty annoying.

So my question is, if there exists a possibility to ask the user once and then remember his decision on the next application startup?

Comment: I'd always recommend - *IF* you believe it's worth having a technically restricted licensing system, buy one in, don't roll your own. For instance, under your current plan now all users have to be admins on their machines despite MS advising against just such a thing for *decades*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Yes that is exactly what I want to prevent to have all users as admins although I could force it since we are delivering the hardware. Though our financial resources are limited to buy one.

Comment: The hard disk serial number can easily be spoofed. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/246474/34115).

Comment: I think you are talking about the volume id, there I agree. But not the harddisk serialnumber.

Comment: If you are supplying the hardware, would the users be able to run your software on hardware you haven't supplied?

Comment: @Neil. Yes, but normally we deliver the hardware, but of course if they have already some hardware they can use it on their own machines.

Comment: "So my question is, if there exists a possibility to ask the user once and then remember his decision on the next application startup?" No; this is not possible. It is a design principle in the Windows OS that elevation requests always require confirmation. You will need to design a different solution.